# Google spreadsheet api return invalid column name for a query when second row is header

Tags: java, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Google Spreadsheet apis consider first row as header row by default. Is there a way that any other row can be made header. Already tried freezing the rows but it doesn't work with api calls. Api calls return 'Invalid column name' which is a valid behavior as header is assumed to be the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this cannot be changed. As stated on the documentation: the list feed treats the first row of the worksheet as a header row. (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data)